# Transport Security with Certificate Authentication

Tags: wcf, ssl, ssl-certificate, transport-security

I'm getting the following error when I access my webservice localhost/MyService/MyService.svc

> The SSL settings for the service 'SslRequireCert' does not match those of the IIS 'Ssl, SslNegotiateCert'.

I've following the web.config examples as specified in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731074.aspx

Here is my wcf server web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0">
  <appSettings />
  <system.web>
    <identity impersonate="false" />
    <roleManager enabled="true" />
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <webServices>
      <protocols>
        <add name="HttpGet" />
        <add name="HttpPost" />
      </protocols>
    </webServices>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <security>
      <authorization>
        <remove users="*" roles="" verbs="" />
        <add accessType="Allow" users="*" roles="" />
      </authorization>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="AspNetSqlProviderService" behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceBehavior">
        <endpoint binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="Interface1" bindingConfiguration="CertificateWithTransportWSHttpBinding" />
        <endpoint binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="Interface2" bindingConfiguration="CertificateWithTransportWSHttpBinding" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="CertificateWithTransportWSHttpBinding" name="Metadata_Exchange" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MyServiceBehavior">
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />
          <serviceMetadata />
          <serviceCredentials>
            <clientCertificate>
              <authentication trustedStoreLocation="LocalMachine"
                               revocationMode="Online"/>
            </clientCertificate>
          </serviceCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="CertificateWithTransportWSHttpBinding">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

I've configured IIS as follows:

- https binding added using self signed certificate
- Under SSL settings, require SSL and accept client certificates is checked
- The self signed certificate has been added to the Local Computer Trusted Root CA.

I can browse and execute the .asmx service definition, but the .svc gives me the error described above.

Comment: You have not configured your IIS properly for yout service. The sslFlags configured in your IIS simply did not include the required `SslRequireCert` flag, which is what your service requires. requiring SSL is not the same as requiring an SSL certificate.

Answer (score 1):

Try to comment out your mex endpoint. That should get it working

Answer (score 0):

Here's the process

1. Create Self Signed Cert in IIS.
2. Create Site in IIS.
3. Set Site to Require SSL.
4. A glitch in IIS 7 won't allow you to specify the hostname for a site when you select the https protocol in bindings.  There are instructions [here](http://www.sslshopper.com/article-ssl-host-headers-in-iis-7.html) to properly set the hostname for this binding.
5. In your web config modify it like so

   ```
   <wsHttpBinding> 
      <binding name="CertificateWithTransportWSHttpBinding"> 
          <security mode="Transport"> 
             <transport clientCredentialType="none" /> 
          </security> 
      </binding> 
   </wsHttpBinding>


   <serviceBehaviors>  
      <behavior name="MyServiceBehavior">  
         <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />  
            <serviceMetadata />   
      </behavior>  
   </serviceBehaviors>
   ```
6. In your MEX endpoint set the binding="wsHttpsBinding"

If you do all of that above you should be up and running with an SSL WCF Service.

Answer (score 0):

I was banging my head on this for at least 2-3 hours, and overlooked the response above about commenting out your mex endpoint.

This proved to be the answer for me so just wanted to re-enforce the answer above. See the comment at the bottom of Step 7 in the above post:

http://consultingblogs.emc.com/matthall/archive/2009/10/22/client-certificate-authorisation-with-wcf-in-development-environments.aspx