# WCF Client Certificate Authentication, The SSL settings for the service 'SslRequireCert' does not match those of the IIS 'Ssl, SslNegotiateCert'

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, ssl

I have a website that is going to be called from some clients which will be authenticating with client certificates and others which will not be, because of this i have to have iis settings for client certificate set to allow.  This works fine on a windows 7 professional however when i try to run this on a virtual server setup with windows 7 i get the following error

The SSL settings for the service 'SslRequireCert' does not match those of the IIS 'Ssl, SslNegotiateCert'

All iis settings seem to be the same between the two environments

Jeremy

Comment: Please show the settings of the environments

Comment: Does this answer for the same question not help ? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4082951/transport-security-with-certificate-authentication

Comment: They are identical no changes, seems to be an iis issue

Comment: I have also tried commenting out the mex endpoints this didn't solve the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

This can be caused by the IIS settings not matching the WCF configuration.

```
    <binding name="TransportWithCertificate">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
      </security>
    </binding>
```

The error message is very explicit.  It is saying 'SSLRequireCert' or clientCredentialType="Certificate" does not match IIS settings of  'Ssl, SslNegotiateCert' or Client certificates: Accept.  To fix this in IIS you need ClientCertificates: Require.

In my case Server 2008 R2/IIS 7.5 behaved differently to Windows 7/IIS 7.5 & Windows 8.1/IIS 8.5.  In both of the desktop OS version I could run the application with Require SSL/ Client certificate: Accept.

But on Server 2008 R2/IIS 7.5 the page would not load with the error SSL settings for the service 'SslRequireCert' does not match those of the IIS 'Ssl, SslNegotiateCert'  Changing to **Client certificate: Require** resolved the issue.

Answer (score -1):

I got this error while debugging a WCF service for which client-side certificates were a requirement. It had the following setting in Web.config :

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpsBinding>
    <binding name="basicHttps" maxReceivedMessageSize="10485760">
      <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="7340320" maxArrayLength="2147483647"/>
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpsBinding>
</bindings>
```

This gave me the error while debugging from Visual Studio. After commenting the 'security' node this error was gone :

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpsBinding>
    <binding name="basicHttps" maxReceivedMessageSize="10485760">
      <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="7340320" maxArrayLength="2147483647"/>
      <!--<security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate"/>
      </security>-->
    </binding>
  </basicHttpsBinding>
</bindings>
```

Comment: Obviously if you remove the behavior it doesn't occur. You have disabled the requirement of client certificates for your service. It's along the lines of 'If I turn off my laptop, the error will disappear.' If you want to resolve this locally using IIS Express, edit the `sslFlags` in `.vs\yourservicename\config\applicationhost.config` to the proper value. In this case `SslRequireCert`